# Using RDP with dual monitors -screensaver issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, screensaver

When using Remote Desktop on “PC A” with dual monitors, if I step away and return 20 minutes later, “PC A” shows the remote screensaver (from the PC I’m connected to “PC B”) on the left monitor, while the right monitor displays a static image of the right screen (from “PC B”) as it was before the screensaver kicked in.   I would like the right screen to display screensaver, just like the left.

Comment: It is not crystal clear which is A and which is B and if both have two screens.

Comment: A is the PC I am physically at.  B is the one I’m connected to.    Both have dual monitors.

Answer (score 0):

You should Open the Actual Multiple Monitors' configuration window, and select the “Screen Saver” tab under “Multiple Monitors”, you can find setting here

Comment: Is the OP using Actual Multiple Monitors

Comment: Yes, OP is using dual monitors.    Remote also has duals.

Comment: Taufan, where is that setting?